# GitHub Action to build and attach asset to every new release?

Tags: github-actions

I want to design a GitHub action that uploads a few build artefacts as assets whenever a new release is made. However, I cannot find any examples on how to do this. Note that I create release in the GitHub website. This also creates a corresponding tag.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65111985/1256041) is not applicable because it creates the release from the tag. I have already created a release on the GitHub website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trigger on the event *release created* and upload an asset:

```
on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  release:
    name: Upload Release Asset
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Upload Release Asset
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ github.event.release.upload_url }} 
          asset_path: ./path/file.ext
          asset_name: AssetName
          asset_content_type: application/octet-stream
```

Choose the activity type in `types: [created]` according to what exactly you need.

> The action that was performed. Can be one of:
>
> - `published`: a release, pre-release, or draft of a release is published
> - `unpublished`: a release or pre-release is deleted
> - `created`: a draft is saved, or a release or pre-release is published without previously being saved as a draft
> - `edited`: a release, pre-release, or draft release is edited
> - `deleted`: a release, pre-release, or draft release is deleted
> - `prereleased`: a pre-release is created
> - `released`: a release or draft of a release is published, or a pre-release is changed to a release

From https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#webhook-payload-object-35

Comment: Also need to set the `asset_content_type`, e.g. `asset_content_type: application/octet-stream`